# Copy relations from another node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two nodes of type User that are linked to one or more common nodes of type Tweet. An example in the image:

[image]

I would like to remove the duplicate users and merge them into a single node. preserving all the relations from both users.

This is the condition i use to find the nodes that needs to be merged:

```
MATCH (x:User)-[k:POSTS]->(:Tweet)<-[:POSTS]-(y:User)
```

With the following query:

```
  MATCH (x:User)-[k:POSTS]->(:Tweet)<-[:POSTS]-(y:User)
DELETE k
WITH x, y
MATCH (x)-[r:POSTS]->(z:Tweet)
MERGE (y)-[:POSTS]->(z)
DELETE r
```

which detach user_b but don't link the tweet to user a.

Note that i tried also apoc.refactor.mergeNodes, but it gives error.

How can i merge these two nodes preserving their releationships?

UPDATE:

```
MATCH (z:User)
WHERE (z:User)-[:POSTS]->(:Tweet)<-[:POSTS]-(:User) 
WITH COLLECT(z) AS zs
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(zs) YIELD node
RETURN node;
```

With this query i obtain duplicate relations, is there a way to merge?

UPDATE 2:

I tried to use the previous query on a larger sample of my database, it gives error.

Comment: More clarification is needed. 1. Your question stated that you are interested in "preserving all the relations from both users", but then the rest of your question indicates that you want to delete "duplicate" relationships. What do you actually want to do? 2. If you actually want to merge "duplicate" relationships into one, you would presumably want to merge all their properties, if any. Do the relationships have any values? If so, and if the relationships to be merged can have different values for the same property, which values do you want to keep in the merged relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query first delete relation from (x) to (tweet) and then try find it.

Try this:

```
MATCH (x:User)
WITH x
MATCH (x)-[:POSTS]->(t:Tweet)<-[r:POSTS]-(y:User) WHERE x <> y AND id(x) > id(y)
WITH x, y, count(t) as ag
MATCH (y)-[r:POSTS]->(z:Tweet)
MERGE (x)-[:POSTS]->(z)
WITH y, count(z) as ag
DETACH DELETE y
```

Comment: This deletes both user nodes.

Comment: Yes, I forgot one detail: `id(x) > id(y)`. See update.